# what's wrong with my lnmp?

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx

I'm a new user to ubuntu,nginx,and I installed lnmp on ubuntu 14.0.4.This is my nginx config:

```
server {
    [others...]
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    [others...]

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    #   # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
    #
    #   # With php5-cgi alone:
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #   # With php5-fpm:
    #   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
    [others...]
}
```

And I have set 'cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;' in my php.ini.I created a php file under `/usr/share/nginx/html/` named index.php,and the content is :

```
 <?php
   echo phpinfo();
 ?>
```

but the broswer download it.What should I do?

Comment: Yes,I can start,stop it with these commands:                                                     leslie@leslie-PC:~/Downloads$ sudo service php5-fpm stop
php5-fpm stop/waiting
leslie@leslie-PC:~/Downloads$ sudo service php5-fpm start
php5-fpm start/running, process 1351
leslie@leslie-PC:~/Downloads$

Comment: Do you see any in your nginx's log?

Comment: Thank you very much. I have solved it, there was an error in my nginx config